# Does this check avoid SQL injections?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-injection

I need to pass a `where` condition from my client to the webservice, which performs the SQL query on an oracle database.

```
 const res = await db.execute(`SELECT count(ID) FROM table WHERE ${where}`);
```

Since the `where` condition can be totally dynamic, I cannot use prepared statements, a stored procedure or parameters.

Is it sufficient, to just run the `where` condition through the following check?

```
static isDangerousSql(sql: string): boolean {
    const characters = [ '--', ';'];

    for (const char of characters) {
        if (sql.indexOf(char) > -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a complex (valid) example of WHERE condition? Would you allow sub-queries in general?

Comment: Yes, subqueries should be allowed. An example would be "WHERE status = 'Active' and ID in (SELECT cell_id FROM alerts WHERE alert_status = 1)"

Comment: I think then you don't have any change. If you allow **everything** then the user may get "everything". Would you consider condition `1 = 1` as bad SQL injection or a valid condition?

Comment: What about `status = 'done;'`? Valid or not? Apart from that, how do you handle quoting?

Comment: FWIW - any time someone asks "Is XXX sufficient to prevent SQL injection?", the answer is *always* NO. [Obligatory XKCD reference](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not sufficient.

If `${where}` is:

```
EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   security_table
  WHERE  userid        = 1234
  AND    password_hash = CHR(65) || CHR(66) || CHR(67) || CHR(68)
)
```

Then it will:

1. Pass your check;
2. Confirm that there is a table named `security_table`;
3. Confirm that the table has the columns `userid` and `password_hash`; and
4. Confirm that there is a user with the id `1234` and the password hash `ABCD`

This can be used to map your entire database structure and to check for the existence of any data. Definitely a vulnerability.

---

> An example would be
>
> ```
> WHERE status = 'Active' and ID in (SELECT cell_id FROM alerts WHERE alert_status = 1)
> ```

Rather than use dynamic SQL, you can list the valid filter conditions in your query and use bind parameters to populate the filter conditions:

So a slightly more complicated example would be:

```
SELECT count(ID)
FROM   table t
WHERE  ( :status IS NULL OR status = :status )
AND    (  ( :alert_status IS NULL AND :other_status IS NULL )
       OR EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM   alerts a
            WHERE  t.id = a.cell_id
            AND    ( :alert_status IS NULL OR alert_status = :alert_status )
            AND    ( :other_status IS NULL OR other_status = :other_status )
       ) )
```

Then you have a static query and can pass in the (named) bind variables `:status`, `:alert_status` and `:other_status`.

- Your users do not need to know the underlying table structures.
- The code is not vulnerable to SQL injection.
- You can control what data they can access.
- The database can cache the static query.

If you do not want to have a single static query with all the parameters then you can build the filters from fixed snippet component parts in the middle tier.

Some pseudo-code:

```
sql             = "SELECT count(ID) FROM table";
filters         = [];
bind_parameters = [];
if ( [ 'Active', 'Inactive' ].indexOf( user_input.status ) > -1 )
{
  filters.push( "status = ?" )
  bind_parameters.push( user_input.status );
}
if ( user_input.active_status == 0 || user_input.active_status == 1 )
{
  filters.push( "id IN ( SELECT cell_id FROM alerts WHERE alert_status = ?)" );
  bind_parameters.push( user_input.active_status );
}
if ( filters.length > 0 )
{
  sql = sql + " WHERE " + filters.join( " AND " );
}
db.setSQL( sql );
for ( i = 0; i < bind_parameters.length; i++ )
{
  db.setBindParameter( i, bind_parameters[i] );
}
const res = await db.executeQuery();
```

*(The above pseudo-code is to indicate the concept of building the query dynamically in the middle tier from fixed snippets and does not consider implementation details such as setting the data type of the bind parameters and probably many other things - use the idea with caution and validate your implementation's security before you put it into production.)*

Comment: ... provided the user has `SELECT` privilege on table `security_table`

Comment: I suppose that is what is called blind sql injection? Is there any solution for this? Maybe a list of strings that need to be filtered additionally?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit and if they don't then it will still let them use the same technique to map the structure and extract the data from all the other tables that they do have privileges on and does not make the exploit invalid or the OP's code any more secure.

Comment: @aaston13 The best solution is to not use dynamic SQL. Explicitly list the columns that can be filtered upon in the query and use bind parameters to populate the filter conditions.

Comment: @MT0, I see your point, and would love to do it this way... however as there are almost infinite possible where conditions / and columns that are being dynamically generated at runtime, listing all these columns explicitely doesn't seem possible :(

Comment: @aaston13 Added some additional concepts for how to implement this as a non-dynamic solution.

Comment: This is a common problem and I almost always see people on my team struggle with it.  Yours is a very nice example of how to do this sort of filtering.  Would it be appropriate to change the question topic to something like "How do I support an unknown WHERE clause from a web application without being vulnerable to SQL Injection" so something similar, so it gets more hits?

Comment: I sometimes combine this approach with dynamic SQL to ease the CBO's job a bit.  One SQL = one execution plan except for bind-awareness.  Sometimes I feel like a really complex example of your technique is really asking too much of the CBO.  Dynamic SQL can simplify the end-query to make it easier to optimize, without changing the number, names, or order of the bind variables that must be passed in.